# proto UnmarshalText fails on unknown field

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, unmarshalling, proto

In golang UnmarshalText fails when the text contains unknown field.

For example, this works:

```
rawstr := "knownfield1:\"abc\" knownfield2:\"def\""
var msg pb.MyProtoMessage
err := proto.UnmarshalText(rawstr, &msg)
// no error
```

But this doesn't:

```
rawstr := "knownfield1:\"abc\" knownfield2:\"def\" UNKNOWNfield:\"xyz\""
var msg pb.MyProtoMessage
err := proto.UnmarshalText(rawstr, &msg)
// error
```

Does anyone know how to get UnmarshalText to ignore unknown fields?

Comment: What is your `MyProtoMessage` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `DiscardUnknown` on [UnmarshalOptions](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/prototext#UnmarshalOptions) to ignore unknown fields:

```
rawstr := "knownfield1:\"abc\" knownfield2:\"def\" UNKNOWNfield:\"xyz\""
var msg pb.MyProtoMessage
unmarshaler := prototext.UnmarshalOptions{DiscardUnknown: true}
err := unmarshaler.UnmarshalText(rawstr, &msg)
```